# Definition of the modf() function?

Tags: c++, c, semantics, definition, abbreviation

This is a pretty general question but I have searched around and don't know of any good repositories to find the answer from, hopefully this thread will help others in the future as well.

As I'm learning C I just went over the modf() function and am looking into the floor() function.

Is there a place to find actual definitions of the abbreviations? I use terminal frequently to find how they are used or to get another guide other than my book, e.g. man modf, but I was hoping to find a list or dictionary that shows the actual abbreviation e.g. Int - integer, float - floating point number... and so on. It seems to help me remember the functions if I can relate them to language in some way.

Thank you!

Comment: You can serach in `github.com` for `glibc` code

Comment: Take a look at www.cplusplus.com . They have a good reference and a search field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard abbreviation rules in defining function name in any programming languages, what you need to know is what library you are using, and see into that library documentations.

From the look of it, you are referring to functions defined in *math.h* in c standard library.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/math_h.htm

Comment: Thank you, I do have the library etc. I guess I was just hoping that for some of them (like int) there are some standards! But this is a great source that you've provided, I appreciate it!